# How to remove list of simulator in xcode 8?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode8

I have install new Xcode in my system. Now it's shows me lot's of simulator in my Xcode and hang my system. Please check below screen shot. Can anyone tell me how to remove this list of simulators and set only 5-6 simulators in list.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open devices from Xcode menu `Window->Devices` short cut key `Shift+Command+2` and then delete the simulator that you want by right click on Simulator and select `Delete` option.

**Check below image to open Device window**

[image]

**Check below image to delete Simulator**

[image]

Comment: and how to put it back after removing?

Comment: @vahotm I don't know but may be you need to reinstall it.

Comment: nice) and what about just hiding them form the list near "Run" button?

Comment: @vahotm I'have try that option but sometime it is not working properly after restart `Mac` or may be `Xcode` it is showing that hide Simulator again.

Comment: @NiravD could you be more clear about circumstances? For example, if I installed simulators via Preferences -> Components -> Simulator ( old version, for example ), could I delete this component ( old simulator for iOS 10.1 ) by your method?

Comment: @gaussblurinc Are you talking about that `run` option ?

Comment: @NiravD no, I mean Components tab in Preferences. I deleted simulators in Devices, but old simulator for old iOS still have blue check

Comment: @gaussblurinc I have faced that issue too don't know the reason behind it why it is keep showing that blue mark

Comment: @vahotm. I got a nice answer how to put back deleted simulators.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/231638